# Android application force close calling ksoap web service

Tags: java, android, web-services, android-asynctask

I'm using .net web service to send a json string using ksoap. I'm using a async task to run the web service, it is running successfully on 3g, 2g and wifi, but in running time when internet connection problem, apllication is force closed.
My asynctask is-

```
public class AsyncCallSoapData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    private ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(GPSActivity.this);

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(GPSActivity.this);
        dialog.setMessage("Data sending...");
        dialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        GPSWebserviceCall cs = new GPSWebserviceCall();
        String response = cs.GetData();
        return response;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        dialog.dismiss();
        res = Integer.parseInt(result);

        if (res > 0) {
            Toast.makeText(GPSActivity.this, "Data successfully send", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Web service class

```
package com.mycode.webservice;

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;
import com.quantta.gps.GPSActivity;

public class GPSWebserviceCall {

public String GetData() {
    String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/IService/dayRecord";
    String OPERATION_NAME = "dayRecord";
    String WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
    String SOAP_ADDRESS = "http://swift.quantta.com/Service.svc";
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE,       OPERATION_NAME);

    PropertyInfo PI = new PropertyInfo();
    PI.setName("id");
    PI.setValue(GPSActivity.header_name);
    PI.setType(String.class);
    request.addProperty(PI);

    PI = new PropertyInfo();
    PI.setName("JSONformat");
    PI.setValue(GPSActivity.myJson);
    PI.setType(String.class);
    request.addProperty(PI);

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelop = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelop.dotNet = true;
    envelop.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    String strResponse = null;

    try {
        HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(SOAP_ADDRESS);
        httpTransport.setXmlVersionTag("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>");
        httpTransport.debug = true;
        httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelop);
        strResponse = httpTransport.responseDump;

        String response = "";
        SoapPrimitive result = (SoapPrimitive) envelop.getResponse();
        if (result != null)
            response = result.toString();
        return response;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        strResponse = "Error :"+e ;
    }
    return strResponse;
}
}
```

How can I implement that on running time when there will be no response from server due to internet connection, asynctask should be stop, but application should not force close. Please help me if you can give me the implementation with my code.

Comment: Please post the error

Comment: you added the Internet permission on your manifest?

Comment: Yes I've added internet permission on manifest

Comment: actually it works very fine with 2g, 3g and wifi, but when internet is too slow on running time async task runs for long time and apllication force close, is there need to use http timeout, if need the tell how......

Answer (score 0):

If your request failed then return null. Because if there any network interruptions happens you have handle it properly.

```
if (result != null)
{
  response = result.toString();
 }else{
      return null;
 }
```

or initialize `response` to `null`.From above code you are initialization is observed as empty string.

On Receiving null in `OnPostexecute()` have a null check.

```
  @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
       if(result!=null){
      }else{
      // Your message to user saying that user's internetconnection is lost.
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to check internet connectivity on web service call and manage all scenarios of exception which you can manage using try-catch block.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, am using module "Thread" to create new "Thread" to send web service like

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){
    Thread t = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try {
                boolean testConnection = SendData();
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    t.start();
    return flags;
}
```

to call function

```
    public void SendData() {
        String TAG = "test connection";
        String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/mywebservice/Service1";
        String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/mywebservice/Service1/HelloWorld";
        String METHOD_NAME = "HelloWorld";
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(path, 30000);
        Object response = null;
        //Enable Strict mode for policy android
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

        try {
            httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            Log.v(TAG, "out :" + envelope.bodyOut.toString());
            Log.v(TAG, "in :" + envelope.bodyIn.toString());
            httpTransport.getServiceConnection().disconnect();

            //return something
            return true;
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();

            //return something
            return false;
        }
    }
```

If u use code like this your app isn't force closed by android.

Sorry for something in code isn't good cuz am new of android dev.